# play audio inside each ion-slides when active

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm stuck on a particular app I'm working on using Ionic framework. I intend to play audio inside my slides as each one of them passes by. Let say, slide A has audio A, SLIDE b HAS audio B , and so on like that. if slide A show up, audio A plays. slide B show up, audio B plays. here's a pen on the app.

http://codepen.io/samcyn/pen/vKYRGy

```
<body ng-app="ionicApp" animation="slide-left-right-ios7" ng-controller="SlideController">
<div class="slide-wrapper">
    <ion-slide-box
     active-slide="activeSlide"
     does-continue="true" 
     on-slide-changed="slideChanged(index)"
     show-pager="false">
    <ion-slide ng-repeat="item in items" >
   <div class="box ">
   <img ng-src="{{item.imageURL}}">
   <h1>{{item.text}}</h1></div>
   </ion-slide>
  </ion-slide-box>
  </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!!! I got it. I just figure it out right now.  What I did was to call a function which select all the audio tags in the DOM and then play each one of them when each slides are active. Here's a demo.

http://codepen.io/samcyn/pen/VjYEbg

```
    // This is use when slides are active 
    $scope.$on("$ionicSlides.slideChangeStart", function(event, data){
        //console.log($scope.activeIndex) which shows index values;
        myFunction($scope.activeIndex)
    });
    function myFunction(number) {
       var player = document.querySelectorAll(".audio");
       player[number].play()
    }
```